# Insert object into string

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to create a readonly struct that represents time in 24-hour format, so it has a method that is supposed to return a string of time (for example: "08:45" if 8 and 45 were passed respectively or "03:40" if 25 hours and 160 minutes were passed)

The problem is in the method, how do I return a string with values from the object inserted into it? I imagined something like `return "0{stringtimeobj.hours}:0{stringtimeobj.minutes}` but I can't really figure out how to format a string so that it has values from an object in it. Please help out!

```
using System;

namespace TimeStruct
{
    public readonly struct Time
{
        private readonly int hours2;
        private readonly int minutes2;

        public Time(int minutes)
            : this()
        {
            this.minutes2 = minutes;
        }

        public Time(int hours, int minutes)
        {
            this.hours2 = hours;
            this.minutes2 = minutes;
            }

        public int Hours
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.hours2 < 24)
                {
                    return this.minutes2;
                }
                else if (this.hours2 == 24)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    double overflowtohours = ((Math.Truncate((double)this.minutes2 / 60) + 1) * 60) - 60;
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.hours2 - ((Math.Truncate((double)(Convert.ToInt32(overflowtohours / 60) + this.hours2) / 24) + 1) * 24) - 24);
                }
            }
        }

        public int Minutes
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.minutes2 < 60)
                {
                    return this.minutes2;
                }
                else if (this.minutes2 == 60)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    double overflowtohours = ((Math.Truncate((double)this.minutes2 / 60) + 1) * 60) - 60;
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.minutes2 - overflowtohours); 
                }
            }
        }

        public string ToString(int hours3, int minutes3)
        {
            Time stringtimeobj = new Time(hours3, minutes3);
            return /* string "00:00" with hour and minute values from object stringtimeobj inserted */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your `ToString` parameterized? Normally you'd have a parameterless method that uses the data in the object you're calling it on.

Comment: Tip: look up the `%` (modulo) operator

Comment: Tip: `someInt. ToString("00")` will add leading zero as needed

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought that method needed to be passed parameters, then these parameters are used in the constructor when new object is created, does that make sense?
I can't really think of another way to implement the method

Comment: No, it's an instance method - it has to be called *on an existing object*, which means that's the value you should be formatting. So you'd call `new Time(5, 10).ToString()` for example - and that should format 5 hours and 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need this implementation of your `struct`:

```
public readonly struct Time
{
    private readonly int _minutes;

    public Time(int minutes) : this(0, minutes) { }

    public Time(int hours, int minutes)
    {
        _minutes = (hours * 60 + minutes) % (24 * 60);
    }

    public int Hours => _minutes / 60;
    public int Minutes => _minutes % 60;
    public override string ToString() => $"{this.Hours:00}:{this.Minutes:00}";
}
```

When I run this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Time(8, 45).ToString());
Console.WriteLine(new Time(25, 160).ToString());
```

I get the following output:

```
08:45
03:40
```

Comment: This implementation looks so much better, but I am still unsure on how to inject values from a new object into a string format. Is that even possible? Something like `return $"Object value1: {newobj.value1} Object value2: {newobj.value2}"`
No matter how much I search I can't find examples of code that does something similar to that or any explanations regarding it.

Comment: Another thing, how did you use/call the constructor without creating a new object? Was the constructor called automatically when the struct was created?

Comment: @Akzhol You seem to have the idea: `$"Text: {obj.Value}"` is the way to go.

Comment: @Akzhol - I don't know what you mean by "call the constructor without creating a new object". I did create a new object.

Comment: I thought objects need to be created with `new` or `base`, so where or how did you create it there? Sorry if I am annoying.

Comment: Do you mean in `Console.WriteLine(new Time(8, 45).ToString());`?

Comment: Oh right, for some reason I thought the call needed to be made inside the method, but now it's all clear. 
But I am not sure how to add support for negative numbers tho, so it would make sense if for example (-25, -160), returned "20:20" or (1, -160) returned "22:20"
I can see how to make it work for only negative hours, but not for negative minutes or a combination of negative hours and minutes. Just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I did figure how to implement it for negative numbers as well, but it took a whole lot of `if` statements or I guess I could have used `switch case` instead
. If you do know of a shorter and more clean way to implement negative numbers then I would be grateful if you shared.

Comment: You could just add `while (_minutes < 0) _minutes += (24 * 60);` after the assignment of `_minutes`. That works too.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the *standard* ToString method like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return $"{this.Hours:00}:{this.Minutes:00}";
}
```

or equivalent:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", this.Hours, this.Minutes);
}
```

- The `override` keyword is required because you override the default ToString method
- It doesn't need parameters, because it reads the local properties (`this.Minutes` and `this.Hours` - you can omit the "this."). Plus the standard ToString doesn't *take* parameters
- The first one uses an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), the second example uses [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format)
- In both cases the `:00` means "format as two digits, adding leading 0's as needed" ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier))
- Bonus: the debugger will use this method to display the value of this type

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in [DateTime.ToString() with custom format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). In your case it would look like:

```cs
int hour = 2;
int minute = 1;

DateTime time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, hour, minute, 0);

Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("HH:mm")); // 02:01
```

Comment: I assume this would make returning the string easier, but I am not sure how to implement this in my method. 
I think I still need to make use of the constructor to change fields by making a new object of Time class, and then I would need to pass hour and minute values from that object when creating DateTime? 
So would it look something like `DateTime time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, stringtimeobj.hour, stringtimeobj.minute, 0); 
return time.ToString("HH:mm")`
Would that work? Sorry if it doesn't make sense, I am still figuring it out

Comment: This is a dangerous approach as it does not allow for your input of `25 hours and 160 minutes`.

Comment: @Enigmativity This is just a method to convert already calculated hour and minute to required string.

Answer (score 0):

Yep , you can use it like this way below

```
DateTime time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, stringtimeobj.Hours,stringtimeobj.Minutes, 0);  
return time.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score -2):

We need to do some checking. If "stringtimeobj.hours" is greater than 9, which is 10 to 24, then "{stringtimeobj.hours}" can be used.

Also, if "stringTimeobj.minutes" is greater than 9, that is, 10 to 60, then "{stringtimeobj.minutes}" can be used.

Something like that.